# Regular expression preceding word match

Tags: regex

I trying to make a regular expression that looks for a certain word followed by " not" for example "does not", " are not", etc. There is my regular expression so far: http://rubular.com/r/5bPRtuz9lA

```
/\b(are|can|could|did|does|do|had||has|should|have|is|were|might|must|will|would)+\snot/i
```

The problem is that " not" matches this which isn't what I want. I only want it to match if it is preceded by one of the specified words. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Reagrdless of your problem you might wnna use the space char like `\s+` instead to also catch i.e. `has[space][space]not`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra pipe here : `had||has` (It should be `had|has`).

Which is like saying `"had" or "" or "has"`. So an empty string followed by a space followed by "not" will match your regex.

Btw, you probably don't want the `+` at the end of your word list. That makes it one or more so your regex will match "canwoulddoes not". Just remove the `+` to fix that.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks for the additional info as well!